# Error from Selenium: UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Error: ECONNREFUSED connect ECONNREFUSED

Tags: node.js, selenium-webdriver

I am brand new to node.js and Selenium so please bear with me if I don't give all the details needed right away.

This is my very simple test which I want to run in FF (I found a lot of questions here like this but they refer to Chrome):

```
const webdriver = require('selenium-webdriver');

const builder = new webdriver.Builder();
builder.forBrowser('firefox');
const driver = builder.build();

driver.get('https://google.com');

driver.quit();
```

---

This is the error I keep getting:

> (node:3534) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Error: ECONNREFUSED
>   connect ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:62412
>       at ClientRequest. (/Users/name/training/learningnodejs/node_modules/selenium-webdriver/http/index.js:244:15)
>       at ClientRequest.emit (events.js:160:13)
>       at Socket.socketErrorListener (_http_client.js:389:9)
>       at Socket.emit (events.js:160:13)
>       at emitErrorNT (internal/streams/destroy.js:64:8)
>       at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:152:19) (node:3534) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise
>   rejection. This error originated either by throwing inside of an async
>   function without a catch block, or by rejecting a promise which was
>   not handled with .catch(). (rejection id: 2) (node:3534) [DEP0018]
>   DeprecationWarning: Unhandled promise rejections are deprecated. In
>   the future, promise rejections that are not handled will terminate the
>   Node.js process with a non-zero exit code.

Selenium version: 5.6.0

Comment: Is FireFox opening at all?

Comment: I would also recommend to try to get Chrome running with all the help you have found, then move over to FireFox. At least with the help out there you should be able to get a stable environment and then shift to FF if you need to.

Comment: Yes, FF opens briefly but then closes. Most of our users are on FF so that's why I' m not using Chrome.

Answer (score 14):

Had the same issue. Installing of previous version of *selenium-webdriver* help for me.

```
npm install selenium-webdriver@3.6.0
```

Comment: Thanks that fixed it.

Comment: It's fixed. I guess due to alpha release of selenium webdriver it was throwing excption.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar error but was trying to launch chrome. The solution for me was to install the chrome driver.

```
npm install chromedriver
```

It worked after that. I have not tried to do the same with geckodriver and firefox.